# Paypal button auto-return url not overriding the default url

Tags: paypal

I have enabled auto-return after a paypal customer purchase in the sandbox paypal settings. I have also specified a return url in the settings e.g. `www.example.com` because it was compulsory. However, I want the return URL to be dynamically set in the payment button e.g.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="company@life.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Enquiry Estimate">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="250">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/order/success?order=1654321">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Accept and Pay Now" />
</form>
```

The auto return url when the user pays with this particular button should be

```
http://example.com/order/success?order=1654321
```

instead of just `example.com`

Why is the URL not being overridden? Whenever a payment is made, Paypal is redirecting to `example.com` only.

Comment: it gets redirected to http://example.com/order/success?order=1654321

Comment: @Vimal I don't understand your comment. Do you mean you have tried the same and it worked for you?

Comment: yes, it works for me
When I click Submit, it gets redirected to http://example.com/order/success?order=1654321&tx=75C00905T0249973P&st=Completed&amt=250%2e00&cc=GBP&cm=&item_number=

Comment: @Vimal so it works with AUTO return too? Not just with the normal/manual return?

Comment: You can consider to use Chrome the Inspect Element to check whether your code is really state the correct return address. Will the page be cached and keep example.com instead of the example.com/order/....?